# PushWoosh on Android: `nullpointerexception` when running .registerDevice()

Tags: android, cordova, pushwoosh, crosswalk-runtime

I'm trying to run a [Apache Cordova based app with the PushWoosh plugin](https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/ios/ios-additional-platforms/push-notification-sdk-integration-for-phonegap/) on Android. To avoid fragmentation problems on Android, we're using [MobileChromeApps](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps) to build our Android version of the app. However, I can't register the device for push messages via PushWoosh. The code is working flawlessly on iOS.

The error happens as soon as I run `plugins.pushNotification.registerDevice`.

This is what `adb logcat` gives me:

```
D/PushNotifications(17915): Plugin Called
W/System.err(17915): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err(17915):    at com.pushwoosh.plugin.pushnotifications.PushNotifications.internalRegister(PushNotifications.java:189)
W/System.err(17915):    at com.pushwoosh.plugin.pushnotifications.PushNotifications.execute(PushNotifications.java:390)
W/System.err(17915):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:82)
W/System.err(17915):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:128)
W/System.err(17915):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:63)
W/System.err(17915):    at org.apache.cordova.engine.crosswalk.XWalkExposedJsApi.exec(XWalkExposedJsApi.java:40)
W/System.err(17915):    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err(17915):    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:28)
W/System.err(17915):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err(17915):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err(17915):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

It looks like the Java code fails somehow - but why and how, I don't know (web developer by heart, I don't know Java). The app never calls any remote resources, so the error must be somewhere in the app setup.

Any ideas? All help is appreciated (and might even be rewarded with a beer if you're in Copenhagen).

EDIT: A more detailed look at `adb logcat -s System.err` reveals that the initialization fails as well, probably resulting in the other error

```
W/System.err( 7439): org.json.JSONException: No value for projectid
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
W/System.err( 7439):    at com.pushwoosh.plugin.pushnotifications.PushNotifications.initialize(PushNotifications.java:174)
W/System.err( 7439):    at com.pushwoosh.plugin.pushnotifications.PushNotifications.execute(PushNotifications.java:384)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:82)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:128)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:63)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.apache.cordova.engine.crosswalk.XWalkExposedJsApi.exec(XWalkExposedJsApi.java:40)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:28)
W/System.err( 7439):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 7439):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 7439):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
W/System.err( 7439): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 7439):    at com.pushwoosh.plugin.pushnotifications.PushNotifications.internalRegister(PushNotifications.java:190)
W/System.err( 7439):    at com.pushwoosh.plugin.pushnotifications.PushNotifications.execute(PushNotifications.java:393)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:82)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:128)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:63)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.apache.cordova.engine.crosswalk.XWalkExposedJsApi.exec(XWalkExposedJsApi.java:40)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:28)
W/System.err( 7439):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 7439):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 7439):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
W/System.err( 7439): java.lang.NullPointerException
W/System.err( 7439):    at com.pushwoosh.plugin.pushnotifications.PushNotifications.internalRegister(PushNotifications.java:190)
W/System.err( 7439):    at com.pushwoosh.plugin.pushnotifications.PushNotifications.execute(PushNotifications.java:393)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin.execute(CordovaPlugin.java:82)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.apache.cordova.PluginManager.exec(PluginManager.java:128)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.apache.cordova.CordovaBridge.jsExec(CordovaBridge.java:63)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.apache.cordova.engine.crosswalk.XWalkExposedJsApi.exec(XWalkExposedJsApi.java:40)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.nativeDoRunLoopOnce(Native Method)
W/System.err( 7439):    at org.chromium.base.SystemMessageHandler.handleMessage(SystemMessageHandler.java:28)
W/System.err( 7439):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
W/System.err( 7439):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
W/System.err( 7439):    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

Thank you so much!

[Github issue here](https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin/issues/83).

Comment: Asked the plugin devs here: https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin/issues/83

Comment: I'm getting a similar error on Blackberry, but I don't know how to get at the system logs on BB: https://github.com/Pushwoosh/pushwoosh-phonegap-3.0-plugin/issues/84

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't provide credentials for push notifications. It should be either in your AndroidManifest.xml

Look step 4 here: https://www.pushwoosh.com/programming-push-notification/android/native-android-sdk-integration/

Or in onDeviceReady function, see here:
https://github.com/Pushwoosh/phonegap-3-sample-app/blob/master/www/js/PushwooshAndroid.js

Answer (score 0):

(Starting with an answer, because I don't have enough reputation to comment)

Are you testing push notifications on a simulator? (you mentioned "test device" in the Github issue, so just confirming)

I ask, because the simulator is not able neither to subscribe nor receive push notifications.